# Get JSON Array Inside Another Array

Tags: java, android, json

I'm programming an app which downloads a newsfeed to a homepage. I'm using a JSON file to store all my data. **My problem is that I'm not able to pull the array "comments" from the outside array "feed".** I have even run my JSON through several validators without issue, however upon running the app, I get this message:

```
System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for comments
```

Here is my JSON:

```
{
  "feed": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "National Geographic Channel",
      "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/cosmos.jpg",
      "status": "\"Science is a beautiful and emotional human endeavor,\" says Brannon Braga, executive producer and director. \"And Cosmos is all about making science an experience.\"",
      "profilePic": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/nat.jpg",
      "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
      "url": null,
      "comments": [
        {
          "comment": {
            "id": 1,
            "content": "Great Post xD",
            "user": "SparkWings"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "TIME",
      "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/time_best.jpg",
      "status": "30 years of Cirque du Soleil's best photos",
      "profilePic": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/time.png",
      "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
      "url": "http://ti.me/1qW8MLB",
      "comments": [
        {
          "comment": {
            "id": 1,
            "content": "Great Post xD",
            "user": "SparkWings"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Abraham Lincoln",
      "image": null,
      "status": "That some achieve great success, is proof to all that others can achieve it as well",
      "profilePic": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/lincoln.jpg",
      "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
      "url": null,
      "comments": [
        {
          "comment": {
            "id": 1,
            "content": "Great Post xD",
            "user": "SparkWings"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is the method I'm attempting to use to grab all the data.

```
 private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

        for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

            FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
            item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
            item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

            // Image might be null sometimes
            String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                    .getString("image");
            item.setImge(image);
            item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
            item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
            item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));

            JSONArray comments = response.getJSONArray("comments");

            final ArrayList<String> comment = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int j = 0; j < comments.length(); j++)
            {
                JSONObject o = (JSONObject) comments.get(i);
                StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
                int commentId = comments.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id");
                String cont = comments.getJSONObject(i).optString("content");
                String user = comments.getJSONObject(i).optString("user");

                b.append(cont + " -");
                b.append(user);


                comment.add(b.toString());
            }

            item.setComments(comment);

            // url might be null sometimes
            String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                    .getString("url");
            item.setUrl(feedUrl);

            feedItems.add(item);
        }

        // notify data changes to list adapater
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `response` -> `feedObj`, closing as typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to fetch "comments" from the top level object `response`. That object only has only one field: "feed". You need to fetch "comments" from `feedObj`.

```
feed
  feedobj[0]
    id
    name
    ...
    comments
      comment[0]
      ...
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're asking for an array at the top level of the json with the name "comments", which doesn't exist.  The only thing at the top level is "feed".  You need to get "comments" from `feedObj` rather than `response`.

Answer (score 0):

Using response.getJSONArray() will not work for nested JSON Arrays. The comments object lies within the feed object. My suggestion is do feedObj.getJSONArray("comments").